# AngularJS: Input form does not work inside the partial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The hierarchy of the page is as follows:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
<div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'" id="footer"></div>
```

This is the main index.html which also contains all scripts sources.

In ng-view there's another index which uses header partial:

```
div ng-include="'partials/header_search.html'"></div>
```

This header_seatch partial contains angular based input-form

```
<form name="searchLocation" ng-submit="search()">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="location" ng-autocomplete ng-change="error = false"/>

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <span ng-if="error">No such address</span>
    </form>
```

And here comes the issue I have - the following form does not respond when placed inside the header partial. When I copy/paste it inside the index view everything works perfectly fine. Does angular have any confusion with ng-stuff placed in partials? What should I modify to make it work inside the header partial?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-include has it's own scope, which is terribly confusing. I'd recommend replacing the ng-include's with directives.

Otherwise this should work:

```
<form name="searchLocation" ng-submit="$parent.search()">
 <div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="$parent.location" ng-autocomplete   ng-change="error = false"/>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <span ng-if="$parent.error">No such address</span>
</form>
```

Please note using $parent is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much. I must admit though, this is very confusing that ng-include refers to a different scope!

Comment: Yes that's why I prefer to use directives. If you can I'd switch to a directive.

Comment: It is probably more robust solution, but for now the code you provided fits my requirements perfectly.

Comment: Great! :-) In that case please accept the answer so others can find it.

Comment: I waiting to do that mate, 2 minutes left to stackoverflow allow me to accept the answer:) This answer really did deserve that

Comment: By the way - do you have idea why this search button needs to be clicked twice to work? I don't actually get it, the first time it's clicked, nothing is going on, only when I click it one more time the app starts the searching

Comment: Using $parent is usually bad style. I.e. using $parent.search() is nonsence unless u have two functions with same name 'search' in different scopes. Otherwise just use simple search() - it will find function in parent scope. Same is for $parent.error - u can use just error as u read variables. The only thing that is not working - changing parent scope variable from child scope. (This is $parent.location here) So u may sometimes use $parent for this. But here your parent scope do not need location at all. So ng-model="location" and search(location) is all you need.

Comment: Could you post the snippet code as an answer? If it works I'll proudly upvote it